# Please assist me in locating my error in this MySQL code

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I get an error:

```
    Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'erm.section' (emo:150)
```

Here is the code. The 'course' table is created successfully. I tried modifying the name of the course_number attritube in the 'section' table but that didn't work.

```
    USE erm;

    CREATE TABLE course
    (
        course_name         VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL,
        course_number       VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
        credit_hours        INT             NOT NULL,
        department          VARCHAR(10),
        CONSTRAINT course_pk PRIMARY KEY (course_name)
    );

    CREATE TABLE section
    (
        section_identifier      INT                 NOT NULL,
        course_number           VARCHAR(20),
        semester                VARCHAR(10)         NOT NULL,
        school_year             VARCHAR(4)          NOT NULL,
        instructor              VARCHAR(25),
        CONSTRAINT section_pk PRIMARY KEY (section_identifier),
        CONSTRAINT section_fk FOREIGN KEY (course_number)
            REFERENCES course (course_number)
            ON DELETE       SET NULL 
            ON UPDATE       CASCADE
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

course_number is not a primary key in the table course.

the foreign key in the table section must reference a primary key form another table.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an index on the column referenced by the foreign key:

```
alter table course add index (course_number);
```

(It doesn't have to be a primary key index.) From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of
>   columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index
>   where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order.

Answer (score 0):

```
 A FOREIGN KEY in one table points to a PRIMARY KEY in another table.
```

AFAIK, dropping the `CONSTRAINT`, then rename, then add the `CONSTRAINT` back is the only way. Backup first!

to drop it use this

```
    ALTER TABLE section
   DROP FOREIGN KEY course_number
```

and to add it again use this

```
   ALTER TABLE section
 ADD FOREIGN KEY (course_number)
 REFERENCES course (course_number)
```